# Something is wrong with my HTML code, how could I fix it?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```
<p>Welcome to our WEBSITE! style="font-size: 55pt;"</p>
```

Comment: Move: style="font-size: 55pt;" between first p and >

Comment: You've got the style attribute just floating about `<p style=".......` I'd recommend you have a read through this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML

Comment: besides of that, If you want to title your website, you should use the semantically correct tag such as `<h1>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your content needs to go between the p tags and inline styles go inside the opening p tag like:

```
<p styles go here>Content goes here</p>
```

So in your case:

```
<p style="font-size: 55pt;">Welcome to our WEBSITE!</p>
```

Comment: Typo cause issues should not be answered but commented and flagged `Not reproducible or caused by typos` instead. Such question will eb closed and removed. awarded reputation through upvotes and checked as answer will be reverted (lost) therefor anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

`<p style="font-size: 55pt;">Welcome to our WEBSITE!</p>`

The style attribute must be in the opening tag itself.

Comment: Typo cause issues should not be answered but commented and flagged `Not reproducible or caused by typos` instead. Such question will eb closed and removed. awarded reputation through upvotes and checked as answer will be reverted (lost) therefor anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your style attribute is at the wrong place, Do this instead:

```
<p style="font-size: 55pt";>Welcome to our WEBSITE!</p>
```

Comment: Typo cause issues should not be answered but commented and flagged `Not reproducible or caused by typos` instead. Such question will eb closed and removed. awarded reputation through upvotes and checked as answer will be reverted (lost) therefor anyway.